# Sinon cannot find module '@sinonjs/referee-sinon' when simple use it

Tags: sinon

I am a beginner of SinonJs, When I try to write some demo code, it cannot work, I don't know why.

app.js
     const db = require('./db');

```
    module.exports.signUpUser = (user) => {
        db.saveUser(user.email, user.password);
    }
```

app.test.js

```
    const sinon = require('sinon');
    // without any other codes, it will throw Error: Cannot find module '@sinonjs/referee-sinon'
```

I user mocha to run the tests.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sinon-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha **/*.test.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "sinon": "^7.2.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I need to see the whole directory structure, but it's probably because

`"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha **/*.test.js"
}`

is picking up unintended test files in './node_modules/@sinonjs/'.

Change the test script so that the tests only in your source directory are included. E.g.

`"test": "mocha './src/**/*.test.js'"`

or

`"test": "mocha './{,!(node_modules)/**}/*.test.js'"`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely mocha is not finding your test files. Without knowing your folder structure it's hard to tell. However, you should always [quote your globs](https://mochajs.org/#the-test-directory) in npm scripts. Not sure that will solve your problem here, though. I think it depends on where your *.test.js files live. Try simplifying and not using the glob to start. Just specify the folder. For example, if your test file lives in your src directory use

```
"test": "mocha './src/*.test.js'"
```

If you're going to have subdirectories under `src` you can use

```
"test": "mocha './src/**/*.test.js'"
```

If you don't want to use single quotes you can escape the quotes like this

```
"test": "mocha \"./src/**/*.test.js\""
```

Penultimately, when I have test files at the root of the project and in subfolders I just specify both like this:

```
"test": "mocha  *.test.js './src/**/*.test.js'"
```

Ultimately, I like running all my tests in strict mode so my test command would look like this:

```
"test": "mocha --use_strict  *.test.js './src/**/*.test.js'"
```

Comment: The test has already been found in order for the sinon dependency to be required though?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Tod's answer, If you've got a `mocharc.js` file at the root of project, I'd adives to change it to something like:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    spec: ["!(node_modules)/**/**.test.js"],
};
```